# Why did this method gave the orthocentre of the triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems, slope

Coordinates of vertices of a triangle are given(say $A$, $B$, $C$). I assumed coordinates of orthocenter to be $H(a, b)$. I calculated slope of $AH, BH, CH$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. For some reason I treated these three as mutually perpendicular lines and related their slopes using $m_1=-1/m_2$ (where $m$ is the slope of line). I got three equations in $a$ and $b$, and on solving them I got the correct coordinates. **How did the answer came out to be true despite the fact that the three lines are not perpendicular**?
edit: $A(1,0)$, $B(-2,1)$, $C(5,2)$. Let $H(a,b)$. Slope of $AH=b/(a-1)$, slope of $BH = (b-1)/(a+2)$, slope of $CH = (b-2)/(a-5)$. I assumed $AH, BH, CH$ to be mutually perpendicular. Slopes of perpendicular lines have relation $p*q=-1$ where p and q are slopes of the lines.
Using the above relation I got $a^2+b^2-a-b-2=0$, $a^2+b^2-6a-2b+5=0$ and $a^2+b^2-3a-3b-8=0$. On solving the three equations i got $a=2$ and $b=-7$ which are the correct coordinates.

Comment: It would be much easier if you would write down what you did. I don't understand anything you are saying.

Comment: A(1,0) B(-2,1) C(5,2). I assumed orthocenter h(a, b). I found the slopes of ah, bh and ch using y2-y1/x2-x1. Then i related these slopes using m1 × m2 = -1. This gave me three equations in a and b, and on solving a and b, i got the right answer

Comment: I assumed ah, bh and ch to be mutually perpendicular, which is totally wrong, but is still gave the right answer.

Comment: You can plot them to find that they are actually not

Comment: Try it with another triangle. Say A(0,0), B(0,8) and C(6,0). Does you method stil work?

Comment: I tried it with another 2 triangles and it did work.

Comment: This cannot work because it would mean ABH are colinear, and $BCH$ are colinear and ACH are colinear ????

Comment: It's still not clear exactly what you did. Perhaps you could edit the question to go through the exact calculations you made with one triangle.

Comment: I am in the middle of something right now but i will be available in about 15mins and then i will upload the exact calculations

Comment: If AH is perpendicular to BH and CH that means B,C,H are colinear????

Comment: @Aqua thats the problem. I know it doesn't make conceptual sense but the coordinates do come out to be accurate

Comment: You didn't do what you are saying.

Comment: @Aqua just wait for like 15mins

Comment: I'm going away now for about 2h.

Comment: I have added the equations.

Comment: $a=2,b=-7$ doesn't satisfy any of your equations

Comment: @Y.Forman But if you subtract first and second equation you get 7a+b=7 and when you subtract first and third equation you get 4a+2b=-6, which do satisfy it

Comment: @ManavGoyal That subtraction step is key to why you get the correct answer! I'll elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subtraction step (which we identified in the comments as the step where you move from incorrect to correct) effectively replaces two of the lines, e.g., $BH$ and $CH$, with their "difference" (in this example $BC$) which is one of the sides of the triangle. Thus, though you start with equations requiring $AH$,$BH$,$CH$ mutually perpendicular, you end up with an equation describing the weaker condition that $AH$ is perpendicular to $BC$ (and similarly for other sides) -- which is exactly what defines the orthocenter.

To flesh this out a bit: denote the slope of $AH$ by $m_{AH}=\frac{\text{rise}_{AH}}{\text{run}_{AH}}$ (and similarly for other lines). You start with the equation $$m_{AH}m_{BH}=\frac{\text{rise}_{AH}\text{rise}_{BH}}{\text{run}_{AH}\text{run}_{BH}}=-1$$ and multiply out to get $$\text{rise}_{AH}\text{rise}_{BH} = - \text{run}_{AH}\text{run}_{BH}$$ Similarly you get $$\text{rise}_{AH}\text{rise}_{CH} = - \text{run}_{AH}\text{run}_{CH}$$ and then you subtract the two to get
$$\text{rise}_{AH}(\text{rise}_{BH}-\text{rise}_{CH}) = - \text{run}_{AH}(\text{run}_{BH}-\text{run}_{CH})$$
But $\text{rise}_{BH}-\text{rise}_{CH} = \text{rise}_{BC}$, and similarly for the run. Thus your equation says $$\text{rise}_{AH}\text{rise}_{BC} = - \text{run}_{AH}\text{run}_{BC}$$ i.e. $$m_{AH}m_{BC}=-1$$